# MCMS 2002 - Live Site updated, edit site not

Tags: xml, flash, caching, mcms

I have a peculiar problem. I have a website that is maintained using MCMS 2002, and I recently deployed an update involving some images, changes to config file, an updated Flash file and its corresponding xml file. onto the server. The live site is updated fine. However when I go to the edit site, the changes that I see on the live site is no longer there - the Flash file hasn't been updated.

This only happens with the Flash file and xml (the culprit could be one, or both of these files), other images and files that got updated (both by replacing the file directly using File Explorer on the server machine, and through the CMS) showed up on the edit site just fine.

I've cleared the cache on my browsers, used incognito/inPrivate modes, and the problem still persists.

Has anyone who have used this system have any clues as to how to fix it? The only idea I have is that the edit site is somehow cached on the server side. On the [Microsoft Content Management Server 2002 Frequently Asked Questions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms964276.aspx) page, it says MCMS improves performance through caching. If this is the culprit, anyone knows how to clear it? There are no options on the CMS itself that I can find.

**UPDATE:** I have reset the IIS, went to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Content Management Server\Server\Temp` to delete temporary files, and found only two image files and an `.sdo` file, deleting them yields no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is an `editmode` folder which stores a different XML file to the one used in the Live Site, and during Edit Mode, this file is read instead.